# HTML altering height of input box in a form

Tags: html, css, forms, input, height

I'm creating a form for my website and have the following piece of code for the enter message part of my code. I want to change the height for this input box only but am unsure how to do it.
I would prefer to change the height in the html code rather than CSS if possible.
Thanks :)

```
<p>
<label for="from">Your message:</label>
<br />
<input type="text" name="message" id="message" value="type your message..." maxlength="40"      size="40" onclick="this.value=''"/>
</p>
```

I have tried doing:

```
<p>
<label for="from">Your message:</label>
<br />
<input type="text" name="message" id="message" value="type your message..." maxlength="40"    width="40px" height="40px" onclick="this.value=''"/>
</p>
```

But this didn't work

Comment: You could add: `style="height: 40px;"`.

Comment: Nice to hear that, you are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "text" input does not have a height or width attribute. Since you want to define the height in your HTML, you can use the style attribute. You use CSS rules as its value like this:

```
<input type="text" style="height: 40px;" />
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [MDN article for `<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input):

> `width`
>
> If the value of the type attribute is image, this attribute defines the width of the image displayed for the button.

The same description applies to `height`

Use CSS instead. Either inline (not preferred) `style="height: 40px;"` or

```
#message{ height: 40px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can style text inputs like so with css

```
input[type=text] {
    ...
}
```

Without css you can use the style attribute like so

```
<input type="text" style="..."/>
```

If using text areas you can use the rows attribute to change the height of the element however this does not work with inputs